# Determining the 3d position of an object with a 2d input image

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera, projection

what I basically want is the relative position of an object lets say a cube relatively to the camera lense. So assume I place the cube 20cm before my camera(x3 direction) on the ground (this means 10cm down in x2 direction) and 3cm in x1 direction.

[image: Here is a picture (the camera is placed on a robot)]

We also assume a simple pinhole camera model. Next I used the formulas as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model). Moreover I already have the following data of my camera:
fx,fy (focal lenghts) and the cx,cy principal point. (Tx=Ty=0).

First of all I calculated the distance of the cube to the camera:
I just assumed that I already have the focal length: F=(fx+fy)/2. But I am not sure If I can handle that so easy. Then I can just calculate the distance with:

D = (W*F)/P  (intercept theorem: P/F=W/D)

F: focus length

P: cube diameter in pixel measured at a certain distance D

W: real cube height in meters

Second step I use is the formulas described on the [pinhole wikipage:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model):

```
  x3 = D; // as calculated above
  x1 = ((cube_middle_point_x_in_px - cx - Tx)*x3) / fx;
  x2 = ((cube_middle_point_y_in_px - cy - Ty)*x3) / fy;
```

It seems that calculating the Distance works quite ok. In this part I just do not understand how to use the camera parameters fx,fy cause in the simple intercept theorem I just have a f and not a fx or fy.

In the second part I have strange results cause I get positive values for the x2. This means my cube is kind of flying or? This does not make sense. The x3 and x1 value however seem to be ok.

I use a realsense R200 Camera, which has the following ros information message:

```
header: 
  seq: 9349
  stamp: 
    secs: 1513684762
    nsecs:  32878312
  frame_id: "camera_rgb_optical_frame"
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: "plumb_bob"
D: [-0.07397269457578659, 0.07420530915260315, 0.0004570182354655117, 0.002167842583730817, 0.0]
K: [614.6105346679688, 0.0, 308.61798095703125, 0.0, 620.16015625, 248.9337921142578, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P: [614.6105346679688, 0.0, 308.61798095703125, 0.0, 0.0, 620.16015625, 248.9337921142578, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
```

I used the P matrix to extract the cx,cy, fx,fy values as described [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html).
Projection/camera matrix

```
     [fx'  0  cx' Tx]
 P = [ 0  fy' cy' Ty]
     [ 0   0   1   0]
```

By convention, this matrix specifies the intrinsic (camera) matrix
  of the processed (rectified) image. That is, the left 3x3 portion
  is the normal camera intrinsic matrix for the rectified image.

Comment: about the fx and fy, this are usually the same, you can read in [here](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/) about why they can differ. Also, the focal length can be in pixels or real world values, make sure the formula that you use is using the correct one, fx and fy will lead to a unique f in real world values. About, your flying cube thing, it could be that your coordinate system is somewhere else? or maybe pointing to the wrong direction...

Comment: Thanks, my units should be correct. Do you know how I calculate the unique f in real world values using fx and fy? I just tried it by f = (fx+fy)/2. Hm for x2 i should get around -11cm but I get 0 to +4cm so that is why I am wondering if my formulas are correct.

Comment: As far as I remember this can be corrected with the distortion, OpenCV has a function to calculate the new camera matrix somehow... but not sure if this applies to this correction as well... [this is the function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga7a6c4e032c97f03ba747966e6ad862b1) ... I usually work with equal focal length.

Comment: I think you should take a look to this [post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/) it is hard to explain in only comments, and not enough time to do a full answer, but I think that link more or less summarizes your first part (D or x3). Your other equations I think are missing something, not sure what, I have to write them down and see them in my usual notation to understand :)